# Tires on my Ford fusion

Tags: ford, tires, fusion

Can I put 205 55R 16 on the front of my 2006 Ford fusion and 205 60R 16 on the back? I'm not really familiar with cars at all!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

Can you put them on there? They'll fit, so you *can* ... however the better question is, *should you?* My answer to that is, no. You should, if at all possible, stick with the size which came on the vehicle. If that is not possible, you should try to keep them all the same. Some vehicles come with tires which are not the same all the way around, but those are generally sports cars, like Corvettes and the like. If your Ford Fusion came with identically sized tires all the way around, your best bet is to keep them the same size.

Comment: *I'm not really familiar with cars at all!* Then NO is the correct answer.

Comment: I really just ask because they were free and I cannot afford two new tires at the moment I will be able to save for them but I can't afford them just right now and I still have to get my daughter back and forth from practice and things of that nature

Comment: @ChantelleSpratleySissyLeigh - Sometimes you have to do what you have to do. I completely understand. If you have no other choice, put the "new" tires at the rear and keep the standard sized tires at the front. This is so the transmission and speedo will not be affected, as well as it shouldn't affect the driveability. This is by far not an optimal solution and you really need to get the tires the same as soon as possible.

Comment: You have to weigh your personal safety, that of your daughter, and that of everyone else on the road vs. the cost of 2 tires.  My recommendation: Think about what you value.  Skip the Starbucks.  Cancel the cable TV.  Cancel Amazon Prime.  Cancel Disney.  Cancel Netflix.  Skip a manicure.  Cut your own hair.  Eat rice and beans for a couple weeks.  Buy 2 tires that match the others.  Oh, and check the manufacture date on those free tires... tires don't last forever, even when just sitting on the shelf or in a garage.